# Windows 7 Virtual Machine - "Startup Repair cannot repair this computer automatically"

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine on my ubuntu machine. I use it to do my homework and assignments in Visual Studio. But recently I've got this problem on the win7 virtual machine - "Startup Repair cannot repair this computer automatically" that I don't know how to fix. I've got my assignments on the VM otherwise, I'd have installed a new one. Now I either need to get my assignments from the VM somehow or fix the VM. 
Btw It's an Oracle Virtual Box VM.

One way to fix it seems like booting-repairing from a win7 software, which I can't do for my VM as it can't recognize USB. I've installed the VM extension pack so that it can recognize USB but it can't. Also, I have created a shared folder after the problem has occurred but I don't think it's accessible now.

How can I recover the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to install a new VM from scratch and attach old VM's virual hard disk to the new one as a secondary one. You'll be able to copy your files off of it to the new virtual disk. Then you can detach old disk and remove the broken VM (or keep it in case you've missed some important files).

Comment: how do I attach one VM to the other?

Comment: Not VM, just the disk. It's in a separate file. In VirtualBox open VM settings -> Storage -> Select controller which has current disk connected -> Click "disk+" icon next to it -> Select old HDD.